# How to redirect to tabbed page which is set as not active

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a tabbed form:

```
    <ul class="tab-links">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Pending</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">All</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
          //contents here
     </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="tab">
          //contents here
     </div>
  </div>
```

every time I refresh the page, it always redirect to `tab1 (which is pre-selected as active)`

My problem is, at tab2, when user submits the form and if it has an error, I want to redirect it to tab2 but since tab1 is the pre selected active tab. It always go to tab 1.

are there any way to redirect it to other tab other than the pre-selected tab?

PS: I use alert box to notify and redirect my user if there's an error occured.

```
if(error){
   echo "<script>
     alert('Please state your reason!');
     window.location.href='home_admin.php#tab2';
         </script>";
```

TIA

Comment: on form submit you could simulate some kind of flash session (one-time), then just apply it into the class, if its set, then echo the active class

Comment: actully I use alertbox to redirect my user if there an error occured.
`alert('Please state your reason!');   window.location.href='home_admin.php';`

Comment: is this the same tabbing you're using?http://demos.inspirationalpixels.com/Tabs-with-HTML-CSS-&-jQuery/

Comment: actually yes @ghost..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a hashlink

i.e. tabbedPage.html#tab2

Answer (score 0):

You could use [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to submit your form,then you can add js code to selected tab2.

Maybe this is helpful：
chang your code to

```
<ul class="tab-links">
  <li class='tab1' class="active"><a href="#tab1">Pending</a></li>
  <li class='tab2'><a href="#tab2">All</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
      //contents here
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
      //contents here
    </div>
</div>
```

Js code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: { name: "***", location: "*****" },
    dataType: 'json',
})
.done(function( response ) {
    if (reponse.erron === 1){
        //your code,or only return true
    } else {
        //seleted tab2 code,maybe 
        $('.tab-links.tab1').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab-links.tab2').addClass('active');

        $('.tab-content#tab1').removeClass('tab active');
        $('.tab-content#tab2').addClass('tab active');
    }
});
```

php code

```
$ret = array(
    erron: 0,    //0 for error,1 for success
    errmsg: '*****',
);

echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I use alert box to notify my user it there's an error and redirect them.

`alert('Please state your reason!');
                                    window.location.href='home_admin.php#tab2';`

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to below:

```
<ul class="tab-links">
      <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Pending</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">All</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
     <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
          //contents here
     </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="tab">
          //contents here
     </div>
  </div>
```

I have tested, it works, you can test at your side

The key is change

```
<div id="tab2 class="tab"">
```

to

```
<div id="tab2" class="tab">
```

Comment: it seems that the code is just the same.. i cant find what you edit. sorry

Comment: @oranje it looks like he changed `<div id="tab2 class="tab"">` to `<div id="tab2" class="tab">`, notice the quote locations.

Comment: sorry its just typo error here. but in my real code just the same as @billy

Comment: @oranje if your code just the same as mine, I think you didn't post the key part, because it works at my side. You should post more.

Comment: you mean, when you refresh your page it redirects to tab2 even if tab1 is set as active?

Comment: @oranje yes, it redirects to tab2